# Using values(string) of text in one SWT app from another.(same package)

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, swt

I created 2 SWT applications and I wanted to use the values of texteditor from second program(SWT app) to first one , being in the same package it  should be available to use but it isnt , can anyone help me?

Program 1

```
package gui;

import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.ToolBar;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.ToolItem;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionAdapter;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Menu;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.MenuItem;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;

public class Editor {
    public static Text texteditor;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Display display = Display.getDefault();
        Shell shlNotepad = new Shell();
        shlNotepad.setSize(450, 300);
        shlNotepad.setText("Notepad");

        Menu menu = new Menu(shlNotepad, SWT.BAR);
        shlNotepad.setMenuBar(menu);

        MenuItem mntmFile_1 = new MenuItem(menu, SWT.CASCADE);
        mntmFile_1.setText("File");

        Menu menu_1 = new Menu(mntmFile_1);
        mntmFile_1.setMenu(menu_1);

        MenuItem mntmNew = new MenuItem(menu_1, SWT.NONE);
        mntmNew.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {

            }
        });
        mntmNew.setText("New");

        MenuItem mntmSave = new MenuItem(menu_1, SWT.NONE);
        mntmSave.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {


            }
        });
        mntmSave.setText("Save");

        MenuItem mntmSaveAs = new MenuItem(menu_1, SWT.NONE);
        mntmSaveAs.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                FileEditor.main(args);
            }
        });
        mntmSaveAs.setText("Save As");

        MenuItem mntmExit = new MenuItem(menu_1, SWT.NONE);
        mntmExit.setText("Exit");

        texteditor = new Text(shlNotepad, SWT.BORDER);
        texteditor.setBounds(0, 0, 434, 241);
        String texted = texteditor.getText();


        shlNotepad.open();
        shlNotepad.layout();
        while (!shlNotepad.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Program 2

```
package gui;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionAdapter;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;

public class FileEditor{
    private static Text text;
    private static Text text_1;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     * 
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Display display = Display.getDefault();
        Shell shlSaveAs = new Shell();
        shlSaveAs.setSize(417, 267);
        shlSaveAs.setText("Save As");
        text = new Text(shlSaveAs, SWT.BORDER);
        text.setBounds(43, 28, 163, 25);

        Button btnCreateDirectory = new Button(shlSaveAs, SWT.NONE);

        btnCreateDirectory.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {

                try {
                    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
                    String directory = text.getText();
                    System.out.println(directory);

                    File dir = new File(directory);

                    dir.mkdir();

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
        btnCreateDirectory.setBounds(276, 28, 107, 25);
        btnCreateDirectory.setText("Create Directory");

        text_1 = new Text(shlSaveAs, SWT.BORDER);
        text_1.setBounds(43, 82, 163, 23);

        Button btnNewButton = new Button(shlSaveAs, SWT.NONE);
        btnNewButton.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                try {
                    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
                    String filename = text_1.getText();
                    String directory = text.getText();
                    System.out.println(directory);
                    File newfilenp = new File(directory, filename);
                    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(newfilenp);
                    String datain = texted;
                    fw.write(datain);
                    fw.close();
                } catch (Exception e2) {
                    e2.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        btnNewButton.setBounds(276, 80, 107, 25);
        btnNewButton.setText("Create File");

        Button btnSave = new Button(shlSaveAs, SWT.NONE);
        btnSave.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {

            }
        });
        btnSave.setBounds(168, 172, 75, 25);
        btnSave.setText("Save");

        shlSaveAs.open();
        shlSaveAs.layout();
        while (!shlSaveAs.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, firstly, you have two main methods so something's already wrong. You should not do anything but initializing a few things in a main, but certainly not starting to build the UI

Comment: These are two different classes

Comment: Yeah, and a single program. A Java program has only one entry point.

Comment: If you are running two applications then there will be two JVMs running and there is no communication between them.

Comment: @greg-449 can you tell me how to make dialouge box in SWT using WindowBuilder pro(using drag and drop if possible).

Comment: Personally I do not use Windowbuilder. The [SWT home page](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/) references quite a lot of resources